# Problems with login and index

Tags: php, session

it's the first time that I publish here about the problems that I encounter, anyway, the problem, most of you, seems easy but for me no. I'm not too good at PHP, and I want to discover more (but I don't know where, yes in PHP manual but I want to pick in right place), the problem is:

I'm creating differents pages for the example website, and I created a page PHP login, the code is:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] === true){
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";

    $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connessione fallita: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }


    $email = $_POST['email'];
    echo "Email:" . $email;
    $password_input = $_POST['password'];
    echo "Password:" . $password_input;

    trim($email);
    trim($password_input);




    $sql = "SELECT pwd FROM registration WHERE email = ?";


    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    if (!$stmt) {
        printf("Errore durante la preparazione della query: %s\n", $conn->error);
        exit();
    }


    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);


    if ($stmt->execute()) {

        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        if ($result->num_rows == 1) {

            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            print_r($row);

            $hash = $row['pwd'];
            print_r($hash);

            // Verifica la password hashata
            if (password_verify($password_input, $hash)) {

                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                header('Location: index.php'); 
                exit;
            } else {
                $error = "Email o password non validi";
                echo 'Controlla:' . $password_input;
            }
        } else {
            $error = "Email o password non esistenti";
        }
    } else {
        printf("Errore durante l'esecuzione della query: %s\n", $stmt->error);
        exit();
    }

    $conn->close();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link href="css/styleLoginmin.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="login-container">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <?php if(isset($error)): ?>
        <div class="error"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <form method="post" action="login.php">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Insert your email" required><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Insert your password" required><br>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    <a href="register.php" class="register-link">Don't have an account? Register here</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you see a foreign word or more is because I speak Italian, just translate if you don't understand, and the code of index is:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] === true){
    header('Location: index.php'); 
    exit;
}

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){



    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";

    $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connessione fallita: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Professional Rise - Welcome</title>
    <link href="css/stylemin.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navigation">
    <?php include_once 'menu.php'; ?>
</div>
    <div class="after-icon"><p>Discover your passion</p></div>

    <div class="welcome-message">
        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] === true){

            $email = $_SESSION['email'];
            

            echo "Benvenuto, $email!";
        } else {

            echo "Benvenuto!";
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <?php include_once 'box.php'; ?>
    </div>


    <div class="box2">
        <?php include_once 'content.php'; ?>
    </div>


<div class="box-title2">
    <h1 id="projects" class="title-body">My best projects<ion-icon class="custom-icon" name="diamond-outline"></ion-icon></h1>
</div>

<div id="imageModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close" title="Click me if you want to close!" onclick="closeImageModal()">&times;</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="fullImage">
</div>


<div class="transparent-box">
    <?php include_once 'projects/project_1.php'; ?>
</div>

<div class="transparent-box2">
    <?php include_once 'projects/project_2.php'; ?>
</div>


<div class="transparent-box2">
    <?php include_once 'projects/project_3.php'; ?>
</div>


<div class="form-set">
<h2 id="form" class="title-body">Form Contacts</h2>
<p class="prgh">If you need to contact me, simply insert your data and you will be contacted soon.</p><br>
</div>


<div class="box-form">
    <?php include_once 'form.php'; ?>
</div>

<div class="form-set2">
<p class="prgh">(I'm sorry that it is not present the footer that adds more info).</p>
<p class="prgh">First of all consults here <a href="#">Privacy policy</a> and <a href="#">Cookie Policy</a>.</p>
<p class="prgh">And my contacts are: <em>Email: info@example.com</em> and <em>Phone Number: 333.123.4567.</em></p>
</div>


<script src="js/script.js"></script>

<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Why my user, when authenticated, is not appear in index? And if I do two times, session_start(), will appear the infinite loop that never end. How can I do?

Your answer will be too apprecciated.

(If missing something, just answer me and I answer as soon as possible).

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] === true){
    header('Location: index.php'); 
    exit;
}` will create an infinite loop if this code is already running on the "index" page.  Surely the logic should be the opposite? If the user is _not_ logged in, then it should send them back to the login page? Or, if a user can access the index page with _or_ without being logged in, then you could just remove that bit of code entirely. What exactly did you expect that bit of code to do, and why? (And if you can't answer that, you shouldn't have put it into your program!!)

Comment: P.S. In the login page, `if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}` isn't needed. Just write `session_start()`, always. (If you have a header PHP file from which all other PHP files are included, then just write session_start() in there, and not in any other places - that's the simplest way to avoid calling it twice.)

Comment: `trim($password_input);`...why am I not allowed to have spaces at the start of end of my password? It's hard to see why that would be a problem. You're just reducing my ability to make my password more complex - which in turn means you're potentially making it less secure. Again...what was the logic behind using `trim` here? Although, then again, since you don't actually ever assign the result of the `trim` function to a variable, this line of code actually achieves nothing anyway. To be more successful at coding, it seems you'll need to think a bit harder about what you're writing, and why.

Comment: Also, to make your code more robust (unless you're on PHP 8.1 or above where this is already enabled by default), add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command. And you should never be echoing error data deliberately - it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident.

Comment: NB the expression `trim($password_input)` doesn't actually change the value of `$password_input`.  To do that, you should assign the value it returns - something like `$password_input = trim($password_input)`

Comment: Hey @ADyson, anyway in PHP, I suck sincerily, and I'm doing an online course and, I wish know better in PHP and other languages, but they (teachers) are so good, but they answer me after a day or more. So, in this case I'm doing a homework and they correct, I'm studying from September and I wish so much to expand my knowledge. Because in this case seems that I studied now in PHP and is not like that. Do you have any advice to expand better? Thank you.

Comment: I think I gave you my advice - pay closer attention to what code you're writing and don't just copy and paste things into your code without thinking it through carefully first. If you don't understand a piece of code sufficiently then don't use it in your program. If you think you need to use it, then make an effort to go and research what it does, and/or test it carefully line by line so you can understand it better. These things take time and patience, and you need to apply yourself thoroughly to the code if you want to succeed.

Comment: Thank you so much @ADyson, one question, I'm rookie or a non-programmer, what websites or platforms should I use to start to have to minor problems to complex problems? I searched and is saying LeetCode, is useful or not for me?

Sorry if I am heavy and boring but seriously, I love to discover and succeed.

Comment: Well it's so long since I was in your position that the available resources have changed beyond recognition, so I'm possibly the wrong person to ask that question to. I had to buy a book about PHP (there wasn't much material online at that time!) -  and that's probably still a very good idea in order to give you a solid start with the core concepts - but you'd also want to think about finding reputable online courses or tutorial series which can take you through a series of fundamental topics. Don't just rely on random youtube videos and blogs though - that's a very unstructured way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You have this code near the top of index.php:

```php
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] === true){
    header('Location: index.php'); 
    exit;
}
```

What this means is if the user is logged in, then they will be redirected to index.php ... which is the current page ... so there is an infinite loop.

I suggest you might want to change this code to:

```php
if (empty($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: login.php'); 
    exit;
}
```